# Menu image above background

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to place a image above my menu background.

I have tried `list-style-image` and background image (on `li` and `a` tag). How do I do this?
Image with the menu: [image from menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS7XB.gif)

orange background: this is the background of the menu (the a tag)

gray box: This is the image I want above my menu backround. (the 'A' is where the menu background is.

```
    #nav ul li{
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 5px 0 15px;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50px;
    background-position:left center;
    background-image: url(../images/bussel/menu-blad1.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#nav ul li a{
    background-color: #feb24e;
    display: block;
    width: 153px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the code that you tried to implement. May be jsFiddle or jsBin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you go with something like this ? (roughly) : [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mBeau/2/)

Just create another `div` with `float:left` and give it correct `margin`. Then you can place your image inside this floated div.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this (the div way):

The link:

```
<li><span class="blad"></span><a href="#">Groepen</a></li>
```

The css:

```
    #nav ul li{
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 5px 0 15px;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50px;
    }

    #nav ul li a{
    background-color: #feb24e;
    display: block;
    width: 153px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    #nav ul li span.blad{
    width: 35px;
    height: 43px;
    background-position:left center;
    background-image: url(../images/bussel/menu-blad.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    float: left;
    margin: 4px 5px 0px -15px;
    }
```

So it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index`

Example:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 30px; z-index: 1;"> ONE </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 80px; z-index: 3;"> TWO </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 120px; z-index: 2;"> THREE </div>
</div>
```

The second div would be in the front, and the first div on the background.

Comment: I hopethere is a way to do this without using div's.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

```
a{
position:absolute;
background:red;
width:10px;
height:10px;
}
li{
position:relative;
bacground:url(../);
padding:20px;
}
```